# <center> , <dir> tags have been expired in html5 but when i use them, work properly?

Tags: html

center , dir  tags have been expired in html5 but why below code works properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>Brand</center>
<dir>
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Ffamily</li>
    <li>birthday</li>
</dir>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.
-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: Browsers are excellent examples of backwards-compatible software. They are so complex because there are all sorts of strange things going on inside them to support a number of agreed-upon standards, old (deprecated) standards and often unofficial standards that have gained "popularity" (Internet Explorer was well known for doing things like that and other browsers worked to make sure IE sites would work when loaded in said browsers).

Comment: That's why old standards will often be supported – although you shouldn't rely on this! Use modern, reputable standards for the best results!

Comment: @moqiyuanshi can you enter your comment in answer section to close question?

Comment: @namjoo.org your question has already been closed 6 months ago, I can't answers it anymore